# Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts with Entity Framework and Docker

Tags: .net, docker, docker-compose, containers

My project uses ASP.NET Core 6.0 Web APIs to connect to a Mysql database. I have dockerised both of them. Here is my `docker-compose.yml` file shown below with both services connected to the same network bridge.

```
version: '3.4'

networks:
    backend:

services:
  mysqldb:
    container_name: community-db
    image: mysql:8.0
    ports:
     - 8003:3306
    environment:
     - MYSQL_DATABASE=dbissues
     - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=****
    volumes:
     - ./mysql-data:/var/lib/mysql   
    networks:
     - backend
   

  communitycare:
    container_name: community-care-app
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}communitycare
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: CommunityCare/Dockerfile
    ports:
       - 8001:80
    depends_on:
       - mysqldb
    environment:
       - DB_HOST=mysqldb
       - DB_NAME=dbissues 
       - DB_ROOT_PASSWORD=****
    networks:
     - backend
```

Here is my connection string that I am using to connect to the Mysql database within the ASP.NET Core application.

```
"DefaultConnection": "Server=mysqldb;Port=3306;Database=dbissues;User=root;Password=****;"
```

I am able to connect to the database with this connection string. I have tested using a login api and swagger.

The problem is when I try to run migrations with this connection string it results in an error:

> Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts (See image below)

[Error when running migrations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PA4oA.png)

**Note**: I am able to connect to the Mysql database within the container using MySQL workbench using the mapped ports 8003.

The strange thing is if I change the connection string to now use the mapped port (8003) instead of 3306, the migrations can now run.

```
"DefaultConnection": "Server=localhost;Port=8003;Database=dbissues;User=root;Password=****;"
```

But with this connection string, the APIs can no longer connect to the Mysql database. The APIs are only able to connect using:

```
"DefaultConnection": "Server=mysqldb;Port=3306;Database=dbissues;User=root;Password=****;"
```

Is this normal?

Is it required to have two different connection strings when using docker? One for applying migrations and one for connecting the APIs to the Mysql container. This is a bit confusing.

Furthermore, when I try to apply the migrations to my database using the connection string:

```
"DefaultConnection": "Server=localhost;Port=8003;Database=dbissues;User=root;Password=****;"
```

(Note: With the other connection string (mysqldb and port 3306, the migrations do not run at all giving unable to connect to any of the specified mysql hosts error)

with:

```
dotnet ef database update
```

I again get an error telling me that a table already exists and it fails. I tried to drop the whole schema via MySql workbench to ensure I have an empty database and tried again, but I still get the same error:

[Error when updating database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/srUw6.png)

Is this normal? Does the docker-compose automatically creates the tables when running the program even without applying any migrations to the database container?

As suggested in the solutions, i also tried running the database update with the following command:

```
dotnet ef database update --connection "Server=mysqldb;Port=8003;Database=dbissues;User=root;Password=****;"
```

But i get the same error Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts

When trying the following migration within the app itself, i get the error shown below despite the fact that i just dropped the schema via MySQL workbench.

[image: Error when migrating within app itself]

Comment: When you say "The APIs are only able to connect using ... 3306". Are you sure they are not reaching your host system MySQL (if you have that running?). I would assume you should use 8003, since that's the port you're mapping. You could in theory have multiple containers using the same ports, but they should be mapped to different ports in the network. What error are you getting when the API (your app?) is not able to reach MySQL? Where are you running the `dotnet ef database update` from?

Comment: @Jeppe , i am able to access the MySQL via my APIs. I tested my login apis are working correctly. However, the issue arises when i am trying to make changes to the database and execute migrations and apply to the database. But, i also noticed even without applying any migrations via dotnet ef, the tables are created when i access via MySQL workbench.

Answer (score 1):

In your `docker-compose.yml`

```
ports:
     - 8003:3306
```

[Docker networking](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/)

> It is important to note the distinction between HOST_PORT and
> CONTAINER_PORT. In the above example, for db, the HOST_PORT is 8001
> and the container port is 5432 (postgres default). Networked
> service-to-service communication uses the CONTAINER_PORT. When
> HOST_PORT is defined, the service is accessible outside the swarm as
> well.

Your `HOST_PORT` in this case `8003` is what any service outside network `backend` will have to call to access your `Mysql` database.
i.e Any Migrations you run on command line by calling `dotnet ef database update` can only access `Mysql` through port `8003`.

> (Note: With the other connection string (mysqldb and port 3306, the
> migrations do not run at all giving unable to connect to any of the
> specified mysql hosts error)

**Option 1**

You can keep connection string as is and in your command `dotnet ef database update` append parameter `--connection` and supply connection string with port `8003`.

[Usage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/cli/dotnet#dotnet-ef-database-update)

**Option 2**

Run the migrations in application.

e.g

```cs
using (var scope = app.Services.CreateScope())
{
    var _context= scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<DbContext>();

    _context.Database.Migrate();
}
```

Comment: I have tried both options. With Option I am getting same error "Unable to connect to specified mysql hosts" and with Option 2, i am getting the error that a table already exists despite i had just dropped the schema in mysql workbench. I edited my question to include the outcomes with these two options.

Comment: Option 2. If you dropped the database? Why would error complain of existing table?

Comment: Option 1: You put `mysqldb` as `Server` instead of `localhost` in connection string.

Comment: If you doing code first  approach .drop the database and restart this again run migrations again either with opt 1 or 2. be mindful of your connection string if you running them outside docker network call `localhost` as `Server`

Comment: Yes i am doing Code First Approach itself. However, the dotnet ef migrate command (not the database update) only seems to work when using localhost and port 8003 (host port). However, the API does not work with port 8003/localhost, it only works with mysqldb and port 3306.  The only way of applying migration to database is to 1. Change connection string to use localhost and port 8003, then run migrations and apply it. 2. Afterwards change back the connection string to use mysqldb and port 8003 for the api to work. Is this normal this behaviour?

Comment: No, its not.If you are reading connection string from `appsettings.json`, Then go with option 2  delete Migrations folder, drop database and re run your migration with connection as  `Server=mysqldb` and `Port=3306` in your connection string.Please read more on  [Ways to Run Migrations](https://medium.com/geekculture/ways-to-run-entity-framework-migrations-in-asp-net-core-6-37719993ddcb)

Comment: If i go with option 2, deleting migrations folder then drop schema then re run migrations, it gives the error: unable to connect to any of the specified mysql hosts. The only way migrations can run (even with option 2) is if i set my connection string to use localhost and port 8003. If i do this, then my apis won't be able to connect to the database. and when i run the program i again get the error "unable to connect to any of the specified hosts. To run the program i will again have to change my connection string to use mysqldb and port 3306

Comment: To sum up, it seems migrations can only run (both options) via port 8003 and localhost while the program/apis can only connect to database via port 3306 and server mysqldb.